# Estoy obteniendo un codigo de error en Huawei cloud Text

Tags: huawei-mobile-services

Estoy tratando de implementar el servicio de deteccion de texto en la nube del Kit de Machine Learning en mi app pero estoy obteniendo este error.

El codigo de error es:

```
"error code 15"
```

Que significa este error y como puedo solucionarlo?
Habrá alguna documentacion en donde se encuentren los codigos de errores en donde pueda revisar?

Comment: Hola @Axel Bienvenido a Stack Overflow. Para poder ofrecerte una respuesta, necesitamos que tu pregunta sea clara, incluir un [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Te invito a que revises las recomendaciones en [¿como elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error 15 significa "Verificación de identidad requerida". Antes de hacer alguna llamada al servicio de cloud text detection, debes especificar el API KEY, lo puedes encontrar en tu archivo agconnect-services.json

```
MLApplication.getInstance().setApiKey("your ApiKey");
```

Answer (score 0):

1. El código de error 15 indica que su solicitud no está autenticada.
   Cuando usa los servicios ML Kit en la nube, debe configurar la **api_key** y garantizar que sea segura.
   No codifique de forma rígida la **api_key** ni la almacene en el archivo de configuración de la aplicación. Se sugiere almacenar la **api_key** en la nube y obtenerla cuando está ejecutando la aplicación.
   Puede usar la siguiente API para inicializar la **api_key** cuando se inicia la aplicación. No es necesario volver a configurar la a**pi_key** una vez que se ha inicializado.
   MLApplication.getInstance().setApiKey("your ApiKey");
   Para obtener más información, consulte [Notes on Using Cloud Authentication Information](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/es/doc/HMSCore-Guides-V5/sdk-data-security-0000001050040129-V5#EN-US_TOPIC_0000001050750251__section2688102310166).

Puede obtener la clave API de cualquiera de las siguientes formas:

(1) Obtenga la clave API del archivo agconnect-services.json integrado en el proyecto de la aplicación.
[image: api key]

(2) Obtenga la clave API de la consola API. Para obtener más información, consulte [la API Console Operation Guide](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/start/api-console-guide#h2-1594016582531).

2. Para obtener más información sobre los códigos de error, consulte [MLException](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/es/doc/development/HMSCore-References-V5/mlexception-0000001050169383-V5).